# Mod Pagespeed adding noscript when js enabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mod-pagespeed, turbolinks

I have the apache mod pagespeed installed, everything appears to be working ok.

I am using it on my ruby (1.9.3) and rails (3.2) app. I recently installed the gem 'turbolinks'.

Now the URLs on my site are getting `?ModPagespeed=noscript`added after the trailing slash. This didn't happen before I added turbolinks.

Why does the page speed tool append ?ModPagespeed=noscript to the end of URLs and how can I prevent this?

If turning off a few of the mod pagespeed options were to help then I can maybe do that with no performance loss, eg, minifying js is something I do pre deploy in a precompile, likewise, the Rails asset pipeline does a good job of combining individual .js and .css files into compiled single files etc. Therefore, turning off `combine javascript` wouldn't be a problem. However, I don't know if this is what is causing it, as I implied I believe it is to do with the interaction of turbolinks, my app's http requests and the pagespeed module just not noticing that js is turned on.

I must admit I find it odd that I can't find even a remotely similar query to this online.

Answer (score 1):

The redirect to ?ModPagespeed=noscript occurs in a meta-tag in a  block.  mod_pagepseed inserts this  block when applying a filter that requires JavaScript to function.  One example is lazyload_images, where the markup points to a blank image, and JavaScript is inserted into the page to point to the correct image.

The  blocks are not needed for optimizations *to* JavaScript files; such optimizations will have no effect for browsers with JS disabled.